# gmail url variables

Tags: gmail

I've set up my `mailto` links so that they open Gmail.

```
// you can code a url like this to push things into gmail
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=user@example.com
```

I understand there are several other variables:

```
&su=   // email subject 
&body=  // body text
&disablechatbrowsercheck=1  // pretty self explanatory
```

The thing is I can't find a list anywhere with the possible ones.

Has anyone composed such a thing or found such a list.

---

**Edit:** You can now resort to classic mailto links to pass subject and body params:

```
<a href="mailto:a@example.net?subject=Your Subject&body=Your Message">email here</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why bother doing that ? the mailto link will open the default mail client you have installed
i think having gmail notifier installed is enough 
and that will be better to users with no gmail.
see here [Making Gmail your default mail application](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10966) or this [Make mailto: links open in gmail](http://blog.bn.ee/2008/09/04/make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-in-google-chrome-browser-windows-xp-and-vista/) 
if not i found this example from [here](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000238.html):

> [https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0"](https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0%22) + 
> (emailTo ? ("&to=" + emailTo) : "") + 
> (emailCC ? ("&cc=" + emailCC) : "") +
> (emailSubject ? ("&su=" + emailSubject) : "") +
> (emailBody ? ("&body=" + emailBody) : "");

Comment: perfect! Will accept. As for your question "why bother"? It was to integrate with an in-house platform. We were trying to auto-fill the subject and body fields with some extra-information to lower the work load on people who were giving tech support. The system worked more or less as a ticket system with some special particularities.

Comment: The link to G-Mailto parameters does not work anymore. That's why is recommended to paste the information directly into the answer instead of adding links.

Answer (score 0):

The example URLs for standard gmail, above, return a google error.

The February 2014 post to [thread 2583928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583928/prefilling-gmail-compose-screen-with-html-text) recommends replacing view=cm&fs=1&tf=1 with &v=b&cs=wh.