# Can I make my application open up a new email in yahoo mail or gmail web clients?

Tags: apache, email, gmail, yahoo-mail

I'm building an address book application. I'd like to allow users to click on a contact in my application, and be directed to their yahoo or gmail webmail, to the compose page, with the "to" field populated with data that I supply. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

As for Yahoo I really don't know. For Gmail you can. Just use the bellow URL (changing variables accordingly).

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=user@example.com
```

[It was just yesterday that I asked a if anyone knew where to find all of Gmail's variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611937/gmail-url-variables)

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. Is this officially supported by google api-style, or is it something that could change without notice?

Comment: @morgancodes I really don't know. I kind of hacked my way into it looking at the URL and checking what similar sites already do (including some browser extensions). Thus my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611937/gmail-url-variables