# Prefiling mailto URL for gmail - with from and html body parameters

Tags: url, gmail

here I found of how to formulate an URL to open a compose popup window in gmail

[Prefilling gmail compose screen with HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583928/prefilling-gmail-compose-screen-with-html-text)

it works great, but I want to go 2 steps further

1. I'd like to set FROM parameter. Since in my gmail account I have the option to select from which email I'd like to send... I would like to preset this if possible
2. I would like to do some basic HTML formatting in my body parameter...if I just add **text** it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I know for certain no HTML in the body:
[Is it possible to add an HTML link in the body of a MAILTO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247245/is-it-possible-to-add-an-html-link-in-the-body-of-a-mailto-link)

The hunt for a `from` parameter is ongoing...