# compose email with prefilled html body in gmail

Tags: python, html, django, gmail, html-email

I am working on a django web application. I want to enable my app to send emails through gmail (I can use either an app-wide google account or the logged-in users one).

I know already that I can create a hyperlink which opens up gmail's compose window. I also know that I can prepopulate all the fields (to, cc, bcc, body) with values I want but there seem to be limits which are unacceptable for me: My application requires the email's body to be generated on a per-case basis. This message **has** to include hyperlinks, tables and be an HTML enabled text in general.

**Question: How can I open a compose email page in gmail with the message body prefilled with custom HTML text?**

There is also [Prefilling gmail compose screen with HTML text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583928/prefilling-gmail-compose-screen-with-html-text) but doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: Was the issue a character limit? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

You want to construct a string like this:

```
var myMailTo = function constructMailTo() {
  var newLine = "%0D%0A";

  var emailRecipient = encodeURI('example@example.com');
  var subjectTitle = encodeURI('Urgent: this email is so urgent!');
  var bodyContent = newLine + newLine + newLine + encodeURI('This mail was generated by me.')

  return "mailto:" + emailRecipient + '?subject=' + subjectTitle + '&body=' + bodyContent;
}


<a href="{{myMailTo}}" target="_blank">Send us mail</a>
```

Remember that the string needs to be encoded. This example is just pseudocode.

The compiled example looks like this:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Urgent:%20this%20email%20is%20so%20urgent!&body=%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AThis%20mail%20was%20generated%20by%20me." target="_blank">Send us feedback</a>
```

Comment: This will open outlook instead of Gmail, which was what OP asked for.