# Create a link to the Gmail compose page with pre-populated message in the mobile version

Tags: html, hyperlink, gmail

I want to create a url link that, when clicked, will open the gmail page in the compose mode, with pre-filled data (subject, message body). But it need to work also for **mobile version**.
I know that is possible to create such a link, the problem is that it only works on the desktop version. It does not work on the mobile (iOS).

https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852679/7475753)
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585630/7475753)

**Is it possible to create a link that will also support mobile versions and through which I can pass the initial content of the message?**

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you cannot force a link to open Gmail iOS app since not all users have Gmail installed on there iPhone.

To open [the "default" mail app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607) set in the settings with a link and already have  pre-filled fields you need to use [the `mailto` syntax](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/), example:

```html
<a href="mailto:contact@my-website.com?subject=Big%20News&body=Hi,%0D%0A%0D%0A">Send me an E-mail</a>
```

Multiples fields can set: `subject`, `body`, `cc`, `bcc`

More details form the Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#e-mail_links

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I do not want to open the Gmail application (or any other application) but open the gmail page with the prefilled data (which works on the desktop)